# React- Storing in context or make API calls which one is better

Tags: reactjs, api, autocomplete, react-context

In React, when you have to display data in select box for users to multiselect(using material ui auto complete). Total records count is approximately like 6ooo+. Saving it in context is efficient or making API calls are efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the size is **more** then you can go for an **API call**, by making an API call it will also make the option for multiselect more **dynamic** and benefits are you don't have to change the values every time you add a new option,
if you have like 10-15 values then you can store it in state.

Most developers prefer a API call, you can use [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) for keeping any async data synchronizaion. always the data the client sees will be up to date